# Delete on Postgresql with cyclic constraints

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, constraints

I want to delete 2 rows of 2 tables that have mutual constraints. I can't modify the database structure.

The structure is something like this:

```
A (id, b_id, other_data) FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES B(id)
B (id, a_id, other_data) FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES A(id)
```

I thought that if I delete the 2 rows in the same transaction the constraints will be checked at the end, but I am having an error of constraint violation when tries to delete the first one.

Which is the right way to do this?

Comment: I think you may need to drop the constraints before changing the data.

Comment: `DEFERRABLE` comes to mind.

Comment: joop is right. **If** that design makes sense (which cyclic reference rarely make), _then_ a deferrable constraint is the best way to go.

Comment: Excelent. That was what I was looking for!